# javascript. Не получается преобразовать в массив

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

В шаблоне Flask часть кода. Переменная tr_orig_str = 'один два три четыре пять'

```
...
...
 <div class="tr_orig_str">
    {{ tr_orig_str }}
  </div>
...
...
```

JS-код:

```
$(function () {
  var text1 = $(".tr_orig_str").text();
  var text_array = text1.trim().split(" ");

  $(".btn-outline-dark").on("click", function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var idx = text_array.indexOf(value);

    alert(value); // один
    alert(text1); // один два три четыре пять
    alert(typeof text1); // string
    alert(text_array); // один,два,три,четыре,пять
    alert(typeof text_array); // object
    alert(idx); // -1
  });
});
```

В шаблоне часть кода. Так генерируются кнопки с надписями:

```
  <div class="row">
    {% for word_r in translate_rand_list %}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark col-auto">
        {{ word_r }}
      </button>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

На странице пять кнопок с соответствующими текстами: один два три четыре пять.
В комментариях то, что в alert'ах.
**text_array** не преобразуется в массив? Почему?
Не могу получить **idx**.
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Выведите, что у вас такое `value`, которое `$(this).text()`

Comment: Я добавил в топике, как генерируются кнопки.

Comment: Значение выведите и посмотрите, что там выбирается. Добавьте по аналогии `alert(value)`

Comment: Здесь var value = $(this).text(); я получаю то, что в {{ word_r }}

Comment: Что выбираете, то и ищите, как результат, выбранное не содержится в text_array

Comment: Дополнил топик. Посмотрите, пожалуйта.

Comment: Да проблема то яйца выеденного не стоит. Просто, в этой строке:
alert(text_array); // один,два,три,четыре,пять
должно быть,  как я понимаю:
alert(text_array); // [один,два,три,четыре,пять]
Т.е., массив. Но он почему-то не получается.

Comment: Напишите, вместо `alert` так `console.log(text_array)`. Проверил у себя, все должно искаться

Comment: Если text_array является не массивом, а object, то, конечно, я не найду там элемента массива. Почему после split не создается массив? Пока не могу разобраться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143158/discussion-between-swad-and-hubble).

Comment: Не разу не был в чате. Как там отвечать?

Comment: Зайдите и узнаете

Answer (score 0):

Решение вот такое. В этой строке **var value = $(this).text();** добавить **.trim()**.

```
var value = $(this).text().trim();
```

С решением помог **[SwaD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520560/swad)**. Поэтому ему благодарность.